# If $S$ is a proper subset of $A$ and the cardinality of the two sets are equal, does that mean $A$ is infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove this by using that $|S| = |A|$ implies $\exists f: S \rightarrow A$ where $f$ is a bijection.

I can kind of see the logic behind the implication but I can't seem to figure out how to construct the proof (if $S$ is a proper subset of $A$, then there is an element in $A$ that is not in $S$, so the number of elements in $S$ must be less than the number of elements in $A$, and if $S$ is infinite, then to satisfy this $A$ must be infinite as well)...

Comment: In some cases, this is exactly the def of *infinite*. Thus, you have to start from somewhere, maybe from the def of *finite* set : there is a bijection from $\{ 0,1,\ldots , n \}$ to $A$ for some $n$.

Comment: Also have a look at [Dedekind-infinite set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
If $A$ is finite, consider the natural injection $i:S\hookrightarrow A$. If $i$ is injective, and $|S|=|A|$, what can you say about $i$?

Comment: Thank you, that cleared everything.